# C++ Dynamic Memory Error

Tags: c++, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is my code

```
int main()
{
    char *something = new char[10];
    something = "test";

    cout << something;

    delete[] something;
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug it it opens the application and gives me an error window saying Debug Assertion Failed: _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block)

Thank you.

Comment: `something = "test"` This is not *copy `"test"` into `something`, but *let test point to the address of the string constant `"test"`. You only re-assign the pointer. The `delete[]` tries to free the static string. Enable warnings, because it should trigger one!

Comment: something = "test";  -- This will make something pointer point at string constant.  Original value of something is lost.  Then when you delete something, you do not delete the char[10] you allocated but attempt to delete the string constant and things go wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `something` is a pointer to character. In the second line you change the value of `something` to point to the first character of "test" rather than what you expect, which is to place "test" in the memory pointed to by `something`.

When you `delete` you're trying to delete the memory that "test" is in, which read only memory.

In general you should consider using `std::string` with `C++`. If you're using `char *` for some other reason look at `strcpy` and `strncpy`

Answer (score 0):

```
something = "test";
```

assigns your pointer to an address allocated using a static storage allocated literal. Your original pointer allocated dynamically gets lost.

To copy contents, use [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use strcpy to copy "test" into your array.

```
strcpy(something, "test"); // or even better user strncpy
```

Instead, you have:

```
something = "test";
```

The code about overwrites the pointer stored in the something variable with a new address. The address of a compiler generated string constant. Then delete [] is acting on this new address that doesn't point to the dynamically allocated memory returned by new.